# visp foxy and galactic release fails on ros 2 buildfarm

Tags: jenkins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I released [visp](https://wiki.ros.org/visp) for foxy and galactic using `bloom-release`.

I received a couple of emails from Jenkins saying that it fails in ros build farm, [here](https://build.ros2.org/job/Fdev__visp__ubuntu_focal_amd64/) for `foxy`, and [here](https://build.ros2.org/job/Gdev__visp__ubuntu_focal_amd64/) for `galactic`.

The tests that are failing require an external [dataset](https://github.com/lagadic/visp-images) that is not a rosbag. This dataset is packaged as a system package only for ubuntu and debian. When the system package is installed using `apt-get install visp-images-data`, the tests are able to find the dataset and run successfully. An other option is to clone the dataset [repo](https://github.com/lagadic/visp-images) and set an environment var named `VISP_INPUT_IMAGE_PATH` that helps to define the location of the cloned dataset when used by the tests.

1. I'm surprised to see that the buildfarm is testing the cutting edge version of ViSP available from https://github.com/lagadic/visp.git and not the last release v3.4.0 that I packaged for [foxy](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/foxy/distribution.yaml#L6067) and [galactic](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/galactic/distribution.yaml#L5238). I must have missed something.
2. What is the best way to introduce the dataset needed by the tests ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393672/visp-foxy-and-galactic-release-fails-on-ros-2-buildfarm/) by [Fabien Spindler](https://answers.ros.org/users/3990/fabien-spindler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2022-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution was to ensure that tests are passing when visp dataset is not available (isolated build)

---

Originally posted by [Fabien Spindler](https://answers.ros.org/users/3990/fabien-spindler/) with karma: 126 on 2022-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1